# Possible Mistake in Calculating Posterior of Distribution using Bayes Rule and Integration

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, information-theory, bayesian, exponential-distribution

I have been struggling on a homework question where I have to compute the posterior density of a distribution. While I can compute the posterior, I believe I made a mistake because the area under the posterior density tends to infinity.

I have spent hours double checking my work and have had several friends also come up with the same answer, so I was hoping that someone could take a look at the work and either spot the mistake or explain what is going on.

The setup is as follows. Let:

- $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_N)$
- $p_x(x) = \exp(-x)$
- $p_{y_i|x} = xy_i^{x-1} = x\exp((x-1)\log{y_i})$ for $y_i \in (0,1)$ and $x>0$

Given this information, we can calculate $p_{x|y}(x|y)$ using Bayes' Rule as follows:

$$\begin{align}
p_{x|y}(x|y) &\propto p_{y|x}(y|x)p_x(x) \\
&\propto \prod_{i=1}^N p_{y_i|x}(y_i|x)p_x(x)\\
&\propto \prod_{i=1}^N x\exp((x-1)\log{y_i})\exp(-x)\\
&\propto  x^N\exp((x-1)\sum_{i=1}^N\log{y_i})\exp(-Nx)\\
&\propto  x^N\exp(x(\sum_{i=1}^N\log{y_i}-N))\exp(\sum_{i=1}^N\log{y_i})\\
\end{align}$$

Letting $S=\sum_{i=1}^N\log{y_i}$, this results in:

$$\begin{align}
p_{x|y}(x|y) = \frac{1}{Z}x^N\exp(x(S-N)\exp(-S)
\end{align}$$

Where $Z$ denotes a normalization constant that can be calculated as:

$$\begin{align}
Z &= \int_{x>0}p_{y|x}(y|x)p_x(x)dx \\
&= \int_{x>0}x^N\exp(x(S-N))\exp(-S)dx \\
&= \exp(-S)\frac{1}{N-S}\int_{x>0}x^N(N-S)\exp(-x(N-S))\exp(-S)dx \\
&= \exp(-S)\frac{1}{N-S}\mathbb{E}[X^N] \\
&= \exp(-S)\frac{1}{N-S}\frac{N!}{(N-S)^N}\\
&= \exp(-S)\frac{N!}{(N-S)^{N+1}}\\
\end{align}$$

Note that I have evaluated the above integral using the $N$th moment of an exponential random variable.

Putting everything together, this gives me:

$$\begin{align}
p_{x|y}(x|y) &= \frac{x^N\exp(x(S-N))\exp(-S)}{\exp(-S)\frac{N!}{(N-S)^{N+1}}}\\
&= \frac{(N-S)^{N+1}}{N!} x^N\exp(x(S-N))\\
\end{align}$$

Unfortunately, this density approaches infinity as $x \rightarrow \infty$, and so it does not normalize to 1.

Comment: "*this density approaches infinity as x→∞*"... how do you arrive at that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is not correct. Consider

$$
\int_0^\infty p(x|y)dx=\int_0^\infty (S-1)^2x e^{(-x(S-1))}dx=(S-1)\int_0^\infty (S-1)x e^{(-x(S-1))}dx=(S-1)E(V)
$$
where $V\sim Exp\left(\frac{1}{(S-1)}\right)$. The expected value of an exponentially distributed variable is its parameter. Hence,

$$
\int_0^\infty p(x|y)dx=(S-1)E(V)=\frac{(S-1)}{(S-1)}=1
$$

and it integrates to 1, as it should.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just spotted an extra negative sign that snuck into my final expression.

Comment: Hmm, I used a negative sign in front of $x$ in my calculations (which you apparently didn't have), but that should not change anything. Since $y_i\in(0,1)$ the sum will be negative. Since the parameter in an exponential must be positive, you should probably define $S$ as $-\sum_{i=1}^n\log y_i$ instead of without the negative sign. And then you get a negative sign in front of the $x$ as I then used.